# Sublime Text 3: Syntax highlighting for specific commands

Tags: latex, sublimetext3

I would like to assign a different colour to certain commands in Sublime so that they can be easily seen when looking through a file.

For example, I am using the Monokai colour scheme for LaTeX which gives light blue commands such as `\chapter`, `\label`, `\footnote` etc. For my thesis, I plan to use the *changes*-package so that my supervisor can edit and comment on my work. This package comes with commands such as `\added`, `\deleted` etc. These also show as light blue. I would like these to stand out more, maybe in orange for example.

I've tried playing around with the "LaTeX.sublime-syntax" file and "Monokai.sublime-color-scheme" but I've only succeeded in highlighting non-function words.

This is the code I used in the syntax file:

```
 %YAML 1.2
 ---
 # http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html 
 name: LaTeX 
 file_extensions:
   - tex
   - ltx 
 scope: text.tex.latex 
 contexts:   
   prototype:
     - include: comments

   main:
     - comment: Words
       match: \b(?i)(?:added|deleted)\b
       scope: variable.language

     - include: unique-latex
     - include: packages
     - include: plain-tex
     - include: begin-end-commands
     - include: general-commands
     - include: global-braces
```

And this is from the color-scheme file:

```
"name": "Language variable",
            "scope": "variable.language",
            "foreground": "var(orange)",
            "font_style": "italic"
        },
```

This is the result in Sublime:
[image]